# javascript not executing after window.open("")

Tags: javascript, html, automated-tests

I am trying to automate some stuff on a website but I have this problem where my javascript is not executing after I am opening the page.

the code is very simple:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

javascript:

```
var win = window.open("https://www.google.ca/", "_top");
console.log("test");
```

When you press f12 (on chrome), you can see that in the console, the "test" is not logged, but if you remove the `window.open` function, it is logged. No other code is executed after `window.open("")`, I would like to know how I can do it. I also tried this in the javascript code, but without success:

```
var win = window.open("https://www.google.ca/", "_top");
win.onload = function(){
    console.log("test");
}
```

Comment: Well the most obvious answer is simply run your code BEFORE you run `window.open`.

Comment: it needs to be run after window.open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, that is not possible because, by using `_top`, you leave the original page, so the code execution stops immediately.

Though you can use a delay `setTimeout` to achieve the desired result.

```js
console.log("Before Popup");

function openWindow(){
    setTimeout(function(){ window.open("https://www.google.ca/", "_top"); }, 100); //delay of 100ms
    console.log("Window Opened");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openWindow();">Click here to Window</button>
```

Comment: Can you explain what that `setTimeout` call does, such that the OP can learn from your answer?

Comment: `setTimeout` will separate the callback from the context of the current function execution, instead running the callback function in the next run of the event loop or after the delay. In this case, even setting the timeout delay to `0` would work to execute the `console.log` before `window.open`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way this could work: by using `window.open` with the second argument set to `_top`, you ask the browser to open another page in the same window that is currently used to run your script. And as you navigate away from the current script, it's execution is stopped

Comment: how could I run the script on the webpage I want then?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the browser loses focus when you do `window.open` that's why the code is not executed as the execution is stopped. Wrap the function inside `setTimeout` to run even when the browser is not in focus. Your code becomes

```
var win = window.open("https://www.google.ca/", "_top");
setTimeout(() => console.log("test"));
```